# Java Regex Matcher skipping the matches

Tags: java, regex, string

Below is my Java code to delete all pair of adjacent letters that match, but I am getting some problems with the Java Matcher class.

> My Approach

I am trying to find all successive repeated characters in the input e.g.

```
aaa, bb, ccc, ddd
```

Next replace the odd length match with the last matched pattern and even length match with `""` i.e.

```
aaa -> a
bb -> ""
ccc -> c
ddd -> d
s has single occurrence, so it's not matched by the regex pattern and excluded from the substitution
```

I am calling `Matcher.appendReplacement` to do conditional replacement of the patterns matched in input, based on the group length (even or odd).

> Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "aaabbcccddds";
        int i=0;
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        Pattern repeatedChars = Pattern.compile("([a-z])\\1+");
        Matcher m = repeatedChars.matcher(s);
        while(m.find()) {
            if(m.group(i).length()%2==0)
                m.appendReplacement(output, "");
            else
                m.appendReplacement(output, "$1");
            i++;
        }
        m.appendTail(output);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

Input : `aaabbcccddds`

Actual Output : `aaabbcccds` (only replacing `ddd` with `d` but skipping `aaa`, `bb` and `ccc`)

Expected Output : `acds`

Comment: `Expected Output : acds` should be `acs` cause `d` is on even position.

Comment: it's not on position but on the length of the pattern matched - even or odd. The length of the substring with successively repeated 'd'-s is 3 which is odd, so it should be replaced with the group 'd'

Comment: The code is skipping the first three patterns and only substituting from ddd the last match. That's the problem that I am facing. Because I called m.find() only once and then I am calling m.group(i) and that was not my expectation as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in a single `replaceAll` call like this:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll( "(?:(.)\\1)+", "" );
```

Regex expression `(?:(.)\\1)+` matches all occurrences of even repetitions and replaces it with empty string this leaving us with first character of odd number of repetitions.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7kDuwG/1)

---

Code using `Pattern` and `Matcher`:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(?:(.)\\1)+" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( "aaabbcccddds" );
String repl = m.replaceAll( "" );
//=> acds
```

Comment: This one works good as well. Have upvoted. Looking to use the Java Pattern Matcher. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It is easy to translate this code to use `Pattern + Matcher`. I will update, it still be very short code.

Comment: Does this include both even and odd number of repetitions?

Comment: Yes of course, you can check linked demo or run this code on different outputs.

Comment: I didn't pay attention at first. Totally missed the logic. I feel so long when I compare both of our solutions. @somnathchakrabarti I encourage you to accept this one as the only right solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "aaabbcccddds";
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Pattern repeatedChars = Pattern.compile("(\\w)(\\1+)");
    Matcher m = repeatedChars.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) {
        if(m.group(2).length()%2!=0)
            m.appendReplacement(output, "");
        else
            m.appendReplacement(output, "$1");
    }
    m.appendTail(output);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

It is similar to yours but when getting just the first group you match the first character and your length is always 0. That's why I introduce a second group which is the matched adjacent characters. Since it has length of -1 I reverse the odd even logic and voila -

> acds

is printed.

Comment: Yes the s can be in the middle or anywhere

Comment: Ok got it ! My mistake was I was assuming that the group will return all the patterns matched one by one but it's only meant for the parenthesis bound parts in the regex - only 1 or 2 instead of m.group(i). Thanks a lot

Comment: Lot of code for something that can be done in a single `replaceAll` method call :)

Comment: But I was trying to use the Pattern + Matcher to see how the single-line regex replacement can be converted into Java code. The problem complexity was not the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple if statements. Try:

```
(?:(\\w)(?:\\1\\1)+|(\\w)\\2+)(?!\\1|\\2)
```

Replace with `$1`

[Regex live demo](https://regex101.com/r/L7Ga3Y/1)

Java code:

```
str.replaceAll("(?:(\\w)(?:\\1\\1)+|(\\w)\\2+)(?!\\1|\\2)", "$1");
```

[Java live demo](https://ideone.com/wHokyk)

Regex breakdown:

- `(?:` Start of non-capturing group

  - `(\\w)` Capture a word character
  - `(?:\\1\\1)+` Match an even number of same character
  - `|` Or
  - `(\\w)` Capture a word character
  - `\\2+` Match any number of same character
- `)` End of non-capturing group
- `(?!\\1|\\2)` Not followed by previous captured characters

Using `Pattern` and `Matcher` with `StringBuffer`:

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
Pattern repeatedChars = Pattern.compile("(?:(\\w)(?:\\1\\1)+|(\\w)\\2+)(?!\\1|\\2)");
Matcher m = repeatedChars.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) m.appendReplacement(output, "$1");
m.appendTail(output);
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: This one works as well and regex-wise it is a better solution. I would have accepted this as an answer as well but since I was looking for something using Java Pattern Matcher. Anyway, upvoted ! Thanks a lot for your quick and correct reply

Comment: You're welcome. I included a solution based on that.